# Como Mostra o path do arquivo aberto no VIM

Tags: linux, terminal, vim

As vezes eu deixo o arquivo aberto por muito tempo, e não sei em qual diretório ele se encontra pois os ambiente da minha aplicação são separados por path.

Ex:

```
prod 
/loja/prod/app/index.php
teste
/loja/teste/app/index.php
```

queria mostrar esse path com o VIM. 
É possível e como fazer?

Comment: `CTR+G` - mostra o nome do ficheiro; pasta é o título da janela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digite:

```
:set statusline+=%F
:set laststatus=2
```

Ou, para deixar permanente, coloque as linhas abaixo no seu *~/.vimrc*

```
set statusline+=%F
set laststatus=2
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488717/how-can-i-permanently-display-the-path-of-the-current-file-in-vim

Answer (score 0):

Você pode executar um comando externo pelo vim com a sintaxe `:! comando`. O comando `pwd` retorna o diretório que você está. Logo:

`:! pwd`

Comment: Não funcionou para mim.
Saiu do arquivo, depois pediu um input, depois voltou pro arquivo mas não exibiu nada!

Comment: tente tirar o ! da frente ou adicionar um % no final. faz tempo que migrei pro emacs XD

Comment: o vim já está a mostrar o diretório no título da janela.

Answer (score 0):

No modo normal pressione <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd>